# Run Docker run command from Java program

Tags: java, shell, docker

I have to run `docker run --rm -it -p 5000:5000 test` the command in my Java program.

This command should run continuously,

I created `run.sh` file and put cmd in it,

```
StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("nohup", "sh", "run.sh");
try {

    Process start = processBuilder.start();
    InputStream input = start.getInputStream();
    int chars;
    while ((chars = input.read()) != -1) {
        output.append((char) chars);
    }
    input.close();
    logger.info(output.toString());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

no luck

Also I tried:

```
StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("docker run --rm -it -p 5000:5000 test");
InputStream input = process.getInputStream();
int chars;
while ((chars = input.read()) != -1) {
    output.append((char) chars);
}
input.close();
logger.info(output.toString());
```

no luck also.

Logger is not printing anything. Any suggestion or idea are appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what's the output?

Comment: program executes, not running docker image. No logger.

Answer (score 0):

Since `getRuntime` doesn't load `env` vars, try to use full path of `docker` command.

I.e.:

```
rocess process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/docker run --rm -it -p 5000:5000 test");
```

If your `docker` instance is not in `/usr/bin`, you can find it using such commands:

```
whereis docker
which docker
type docker
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to change the code to get the error too.
if you change 
`InputStream input = process.getInputStream();`

to

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                process.getErrorStream()));
```

you can get the error, you can also get the error separately. If you look at the error, you can see it says:

```
the input device is not a TTY
```

which I think it mens, the `Runtime.getRuntime()` is not a TTY so you cant run the docker in the interactive (`-it`) mode.